# Outlook 2013 showing "sent" email as "draft" item in "Sent" folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, eset

I have an issue on my work computer. As explained in the title,
Sent message move to "Sent" folder (IMAP), but it shows as a draft in the "sent" folder.
- Sent items are showing at webmail too, but in draft form as in Outlook.
- Already I have removed and recreated my email account
- Already I have re-install outlook.
- My "draft" directory is overfill with mail That Are not supposed to be there. I always use my draft to store important email That need some checking, it's frustrating the fact that i have to delete the "trash" manually.
I have not found any valid indication about the problem on answer.microsoft.com.

I thought it would be a problem with the antivirus ESET Nod, but also temporarily disabling the problem persists. By contacting ESET support, they have ruled out the possibility of their responsibilities.

Is it a client issue or a mailserver issue?
Our mail server is SME server. 
is there any chance that the problem is "communication" between the linux server and outlook 2013?
and if so where should I look to find a solution?
By trying to setup email on Thunderbird, everything works perfectly and the problem does not occur.
I hope I was as specific as possible, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Symantec/PGP Encryption Desktop?
I've the same issue using it's email proxy.
There's a known bug opened since July 7, 2014.
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH222712.html

It's very frustrating...

Comment: I'm not using Symantec Encription, but,a similar thread was also open on ESET support system and "solved" last year. 
ESET claims to be a problem in Office 2013.